# Create multiple lattice plots using for

Tags: r, for-loop, lattice

I'm trying to generate multiple plots using a lattice command, as follows:

```
variable <- (string with variable names)

for (i in 1:X){

 mypath <- paste(i,' - ',variable[i],'.png',sep='')
 png(mypath,width=760)

  xyplot(get(variable[i]) ~ GroupVariable, groups = IDvariable,
         data = dataset,
         type = "l" )

 dev.off()
}
```

The problem is, although the individual piece of code works fine, when executing the for loop the files are generated without any plot. The code works fine with other plots not generated by lattice. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Regards,
David

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create multiple lattice plots from a data table using lapply in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476708/create-multiple-lattice-plots-from-a-data-table-using-lapply-in-r)

Comment: Your probably need `print(xyplot(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

#### `print(xyplot(...))` should help

The lattice function `xyplot()` does not produce any output when it is called in another function (i.e. a for loop). Hence, in a loop the output of `xyplot()` has to be printed in in an extra step.

I had the same problem and this post explained everything:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-May/071467.html

To solve your problem you have to put the `xyplot()` call inside `print()`. Your code example should work like this:

```
variable <- (string with variable names)

for (i in 1:X){

 mypath <- paste(i,' - ',variable[i],'.png',sep='')
 png(mypath,width=760)

 print(xyplot(get(variable[i]) ~ GroupVariable, groups = IDvariable,
        data = dataset,
        type = "l"))
 dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the operations in a function with `lapply` for index traversal is a scalable solution.
    `facet_grid` from ggplot provides alternative plotting scheme.

Note usage of `aes_string` for usage with string variables and `as.formula` to contruct dynamic formulae.

```
data(mtcars)

library("lattice")
library("ggplot2")


 fn_exportPlot = function(
 dataObj = mtcars, 
 indepVar  = "cyl", 
 depVar = "mpg",
 groupVar = "am",
 plotEngine=c("lattice","ggplot")) {

filePath =  paste0(indepVar,"_",plotEngine,'.png')

png(filePath,width=760) 


if(plotEngine=="lattice"){ 

formulaVar = as.formula(paste0(depVar," ~ ",indepVar,"|",groupVar))

 print(xyplot(formulaVar,data=dataObj))

}else{

 groupForm = as.formula(paste0("~ ",groupVar))

 gg = ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(indepVar,depVar)) + geom_point(shape=1) + facet_grid(groupForm)

 print(gg)


}

dev.off()


}

varList = c("cyl","disp")

lapply(varList,function(x) fn_exportPlot(indepVar = x,plotEngine="lattice") )
lapply(varList,function(x) fn_exportPlot(indepVar = x,plotEngine="ggplot") )
```

**Plots:**
[image]

[image]